# Passing a member variable as a parameter in a method of the same class

Tags: design-patterns

I'm developing a game with Unreal Engine and I have a class that represent something (a pawn) that I can move inside the game's level. I'm using Spherical coordinates to move it.

This class has a method to convert its spherical coordinates into a Cartesian location because Unreal uses Cartesian location to place pawns inside the level.

A piece of the class is:

```
struct SphericalCoordinates
{
    float Radius;
    float Azimuth;
    float Zenit;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    // Convert a spherical coordiantes to cartesian coordiantes.
    FVector SphericalToCartesian(SphericalCoordinates Spherical) const;


private:

    SphericalCoordinates SphereCoors;
    
}
```

The private member `SphericalCoordinates SphereCoors` is the one that I'm going to pass to the method `SphericalToCartesian` as its parameter. In other words, inside the same class, `MyClass` I'm going to call it in this way:

```
SphericalToCartesian(SphereCoors);
```

I use the member variable `SphereCoors` to store the spherical coordinates of the class instead of compute it every time I need it.

Is it a good idea to pass a member variable as a parameter in a method of the same class?

Of course, I think I can move this method to another class because it only does coordinates transformations, but I think it is a good question to ask if it is a good design to pass a member variable as a parameter in a method of the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific question "Is it a good idea to pass a member variable as a parameter in a method of the same class?" - There is **no** need to pass member variable, since the member function already have access to those anyways.

But you need to know the below as well, since this is more of a approach of implementation question.

If your `MyClass` is only responsible for a game object(pawn), then a very `generic` operation of *converting* from Spherical to Cartesian co-ordinates must *not* be implemented inside that class.
Prefer to write a utility class that can do these kind of generic operations[unit conversions, etc]. You can create such a class and implement the `SphericalToCartesian` function inside that class.

Then the MyClass can call that utility class' function and pass it's member `SphereCoors`.  Like so,

```
class Utility
{
   public static void SphericalToCartesian(SphericalCoordinates sphereCoOrds)
   {
      //do your conversion here
      //you can return cartesian co-ords OR
      //change the input argument's values, upto you
   }
}
```

consume in your myClass

```
  Utility.SphericalToCartesian(SphereCoors);
```

Comment: I think I have added a parameter to the method because I was thinking, unconscious, that this is the way I will use it in an utility class. Thank you.